# concatenate a string/character n number of times in xpath

Tags: xpath, esb, messagebroker

I am using a mapping node in my messageflow and there is a part where i need to 
conatenate a string/character n times in xpath function.
Is there any way to do this with some
xpath expression or xpath build function (or both) ? 
for example: concatenate '~' 17 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy in XPath 2.0:

```
string-join(for $i in 1 to 17 return '~', '')
```

Easier still in XPath 3.0:

```
string-join((1 to 17)!'~')
```

In XPath 1.0 your best bet is probably to initialize a variable $tildes with 100 (or however many) tildes, and then use

```
substring($tildes, 1, 17)
```