# XPath only append text if there is a match

Tags: xpath, saxon

In Java 17 I'm using XPath to extract data from XML by joining all the `<bar>`s under `<foo>`. I'm using Saxon 12, but I'm doing it through the JAXP API. I create an `XPathExpression` and then invoke it like this:

```java
(String)xpathExpression.evaluate(context, XPathConstants.STRING)
```

I was hoping that this would give me a `null` if there was no match. But apparently this is not the case. Let's start with this XPath expression (simplified from what I'm using)

```
/foo/string-join(bar, codepoints-to-string(10))
```

I wanted this to join all the `/foo/bar` strings together, separated by newlines, which it does if there is a `/foo`. But if there is no `/foo`, then instead of returning `null` it seems to return an empty string.

My first question would be how to detect that this XPath expression did not match `/foo/`. I had assumed that `XPathExpression.evaluate()` would return `null` if there was no match. (Reading the API now I guess that was just an assumption I made.)

But let's say that I'm OK with returning an empty string, and I can detect if the returned string is empty and consider that a non-match (even though semantically that is not ideal). The problem is that I want the value to end with a newline as well, so my expression looks like this:

```
concat(/foo/string-join(bar, codepoints-to-string(10)), codepoints-to-string(10))
```

This is worse—now if there is no `/foo`, it returns a string with a single newline `\n`, because it appends the newline to the thing-that-did-not-match which it considered the empty string.

I would prefer to find a way for this expression to return `null` in JAXP if `/foo` does not exist. But if that can't easily be done, I'd prefer to still at least get an empty string if `/foo` does not exist, i.e. `concat()` only appends text if the inner match is successful. I have a feeling I'll have to construct some elaborate work around, but maybe an XPath expert knows a trick or two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the JAXP interface with XPath 2.0, you run into the problem that the JAXP specification doesn't say what happens when the expression returns values outside the XPath 1.0 type system. So Saxon does its best to interpret the intent.

If there is no `foo` element then the XPath expression returns an empty sequence. JAXP says that the raw result is converted to the required return type using XPath conversion rules. Now, in XPath 2.0 the `string()` function applied to an empty sequence returns a zero-length string, while the `xs:string()` constructor returns an empty sequence, which one might (perhaps) interpret as equivalent to a Java null. But Saxon chooses the `string()` conversion and returns a zero length string.

My advice would be to switch to the s9api interface which gives you full access to the XPath 2.0 type system. I would probably write an expression that returns a sequence of strings, and write the code to convert this into a single string in Java rather than in XPath.

But if you want to stick with JAXP, you could use the XPath expression

```
string-join(/foo/(bar || '\n'))
```

(Note, the `\n` is converted to a newline by the Java compiler, not by the XPath engine).

Comment: Thanks again for the quick answer and as usual excellent information. I have no problem with there being an s9api, and I am sure (as it has the experience of hindsight) that it is more elegant and faster than the JAXP interface. Nevertheless in my case, I am writing a general platform that will allow pluggable processing, and it may be that the processors want to manipulate the DOM, and for an industry-wide platform that I prefer to stick with the DOM for interoperability and for low learning curve, so I intend to parse the source documents to the W3C DOM, even if I us Saxon for XPath/XSLT.

Comment: "(Note, the `\n` is converted to a newline by the Java compiler, not by the XPath engine)." We can pass literal newlines to XPath?  So I don't have to use `codepoints-to-string(10)`? I'll try that.

Comment: Yes, newline is a valid character in an XPath string literal.

Comment: I assume you're aware that Saxon will work with DOM whether you use the JAXP or the s9api interface? Saxon's TinyTree is 5-10 times faster, and considerably smaller, but if you want to use DOM then you can.

Comment: "I assume you're aware that Saxon will work with DOM whether you use the JAXP or the s9api interface?" Ah, no I didn't, thanks. But first let me try to wrap my head around this `|| '\n'` stuff first. I'm not quite getting it to work yet in my (more complex) XPath expression.

Comment: Whew—I think I did it! My real example was more complex, in that it had nested string joins for collections of lines (with double newlines for line groupings). The trick is that I put the `string-join(… || '\n')` just under the missing element, so if the match never gets that far I suppose the trailing newline is never union-ed with the match. Thank you! I'm going to rest my brain for the day and test the intricacies of this tomorrow.

Comment: I'm still left with assuming that an empty string means "no match", which feels dirty (and technically isn't accurate). I suppose I could extend the same technique you explained to go old school on it (DOS batch file empty string detection anyone?) and append a unique token (e.g. `string-join(… || '\n$MATCHED_DELETE_THIS')` which would only get appended if matched. That's even dirtier but perhaps more accurate.

Comment: Well, JAXP is constrained to return one of the four types of XPath 1.0 value: a node-set, a string, a number, or a boolean, and I'm afraid that rather limits the possibilities.

Comment: "I assume you're aware that Saxon will work with DOM whether you use the JAXP or the s9api interface?" I took s9api code `XPathSelector.setContextItem(XdmItem)` and tried to change that to use a `org.w3c.dom.Document` as the context, but such a method isn't available. Perhaps I misunderstood what "Saxon will work with DOM" means. I don't want to get this discussion too far off-topic from the Stack Overflow question; if you have a link to the API or documentation on how the s9api could do an XPath query on a`org.w3c.dom.Document`, I can go read more.

Comment: @GarretWilson, I think one option is https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/DocumentBuilder.html#wrap(java.lang.Object) where you can wrap a DOM `Node` to get an `XdmNode`.